# Have I gone about this Q&A the wrong way?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, self-answer

So I wanted to write a good answer to the *There something wrong with my JavaScript please help* type question. Where the person asking obviously has made no attempt or has no idea how to debug their JavaScript.

So I wrote this [How do I debug JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623572/how-do-i-debug-javascript/19623573?noredirect=1#comment29132442_19623573)

Good idea? Have I gone about this the right way?

I did check, for quite a while for duplicates but couldn't find one. Someone has flagged it as a duplicate, should I of provided my answer in the duplicate?

I've given this quite a lot of thought in an attempt to help people so please be kind :)

Any suggestions or constructive criticism welcome though!

Comment: You should specify that was a self-answered question.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, How? this is new to me? I did click the *Answer my own question* tick box?

Comment: If you couldn't find a duplicate initially then everything up to that point is fair enough. If both questions have good answers then flag for a merge

Comment: @Liam, I mean, in your meta-question (this question).

Comment: I didn't read everything thoroughly, but it does indeed look like an exact duplicate; however, you did provide an excellent answer. If anything, the answer should be merged/added to the other one.

Comment: @RichardTingle, how would I do that?

Comment: Flag under "other" and explain the situation. Including 'What you want the moderator to do' and 'Why you want them to do it'

Comment: I've flagged it and asked to be merged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you find that two questions are duplicates of each other **and both have excellent answers** then they are candidates to be merged; putting all the good answers in a single place.

The merge requires a moderator so flag your question under "other" and explain the situation. Remember to include;

- What you want the moderator to do
- Why you want them to do it

Moderator flags are handled fast so try to be as clear as possible.

Comment: Question has been merged.

Comment: Cheers @Shog9..